# App crashing upon release possible due to minSDKversion &targetSDKversion

Tags: android, google-play, flutter

My app is crashing as soon as you open it and i think is has something to do with my deployment steps that i followed here (https://flutter.io/android-release/) and i'm trying to eliminate reasons as to why.

I followed all the steps but the only part i couldn't understand is the  minSDKversion & targetSDKversion.

my sdk manager shows that i have Android 8.1 (oreo) partially installed and Android API 28 installed.

so my minSDK is set at 16 and my targetSDK is set at 27, and i know it should be 28

my problem is that i read that it wont even install on someones phone if those min/target SDK's are wrong(and i'm able to install from google play), and i'm trying to double check if that is really the case; Could this be the reason that its crashing upon opening?

my backtrace:

backtrace:

```
#00  pc 000000000001cd66  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+58)
  #01  pc 000000000005b861  /data/app/my.mobile.app-8xh_NkCMyBUcRItBeV9kLg==/lib/arm/libflutter.so
  #02  pc 000000000004ff59  /data/app/my.mobile.app-8xh_NkCMyBUcRItBeV9kLg==/lib/arm/libflutter.so (JNI_OnLoad+72)
  #03  pc 0000000000234d79  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, _jobject*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+2324)
  #04  pc 0000000000002f5b  /system/lib/libopenjdkjvm.so (JVM_NativeLoad+230)
  #05  pc 000000000010c733  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad [DEDUPED]+130)
  #06  pc 000000000016708b  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0+146)
  #07  pc 000000000016b94f  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.System.loadLibrary+86)
  #08  pc 000000000040d575  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #09  pc 00000000003e6c7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
  #10  pc 00000000000a1027  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
  #11  pc 00000000001e5ae9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+236)
  #12  pc 00000000001e05d7  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+814)
  #13  pc 00000000003e27af  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+130)
  #14  pc 0000000000400494  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #15  pc 0000000000008ed4  /data/app/my.mobile.app-8xh_NkCMyBUcRItBeV9kLg==/oat/arm/base.vdex (io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.a+80)
  #16  pc 00000000001c4d53  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2471763592+378)
  #17  pc 00000000001c9439  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+152)
  #18  pc 00000000001e05bf  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+790)
  #19  pc 00000000003e27af  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+130)
  #20  pc 0000000000400494  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #21  pc 0000000000008e6a  /data/app/my.mobile.app-8xh_NkCMyBUcRItBeV9kLg==/oat/arm/base.vdex (io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.a+10)
  #22  pc 00000000001c4d53  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2471763592+378)
  #23  pc 00000000001c937f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+82)
  #24  pc 00000000003d52b9  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+880)
  #25  pc 0000000000411aff  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+30)
  #26  pc 000000000040d575  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #27  pc 00000000003e6c7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
  #28  pc 00000000000a1027  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
  #29  pc 00000000001e5ae9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+236)
  #30  pc 00000000001e05d7  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+814)
  #31  pc 00000000003e27af  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+130)
  #32  pc 0000000000400494  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #33  pc 0000000000007b8a  /data/app/my.mobile.app-8xh_NkCMyBUcRItBeV9kLg==/oat/arm/base.vdex (io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication.onCreate+6)
  #34  pc 00000000001c4d53  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2471763592+378)
  #35  pc 00000000001c937f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+82)
  #36  pc 00000000003d52b9  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+880)
  #37  pc 0000000000411aff  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+30)
  #38  pc 000000000067a899  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate+40)
  #39  pc 000000000075a4bb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication+6626)
  #40  pc 0000000000756435  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+5788)
  #41  pc 000000000090e329  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+136)
  #42  pc 0000000000910a23  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1162)
  #43  pc 000000000075f6b3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+674)
  #44  pc 000000000040d575  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #45  pc 00000000003e6c7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
  #46  pc 00000000000a1027  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
  #47  pc 0000000000347ac5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
  #48  pc 0000000000348f15  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+1024)
  #49  pc 00000000002fb0c5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+40)
  #50  pc 000000000011226f  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+110)
  #51  pc 0000000000a0a56b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+114)
  #52  pc 0000000000a10455  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2836)
  #53  pc 000000000040d575  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #54  pc 00000000003e6c7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
  #55  pc 00000000000a1027  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
  #56  pc 0000000000347ac5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
  #57  pc 00000000003478ef  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+310)
  #58  pc 000000000028eb11  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+444)
  #59  pc 000000000006c93b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+30)
  #60  pc 000000000006eb93  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+458)
  #61  pc 0000000000001989  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+728)
  #62  pc 000000000008ae6d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
  #63  pc 000000000000166f  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+38)
  #64  pc 0000000000000306  <anonymous>
```

Comment: Instead of just guessing what the reason could be, try getting a stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: I planned on doing that but i don't have an android phone on me and wont for sometime, all i have are emulators and they don't crash on that

Comment: If this is on the Play Store, there's a "Crashes and ANRs" section under "Android Vitals" where you can see all stacktraces.

Comment: Ok i posted it, but have zero idea on how to read it

Comment: That's an ANR trace. Click the "Crashes" tab.

Comment: I am on the crashes tab, the ANR tab has no data in ti

Comment: What versions of Android is this crashing on?

Comment: The phone was running android 9